# Office floor assignment

Tags: logical-deduction

A real estate developer has built a new office building of six floors, and numbered the floors 1 through 6 from bottom to top. Each of the six companies — F, G, I, J, K, and M — must be assigned an entire floor for office space. The floors must be assigned according to the following conditions:

- F must be on a floor lower than G
- I must be either on the floor immediately above M or on the floor immediately below M
- J can be neither on the floor immediately above M not the floor immediately below M
- K must be on floor 4

> **Q7: Which of the following is an acceptable assignment of companies to floors 1 through 6?**

G, I, M, K, F, J

J, F, G, K, I, M

J, M, I, F, G, K

K, F, J, G, M, I

> **Q8: If M is on floor 2, any one of the following could be true EXCEPT:**

F is on floor 3

I is on floor 1

K is on floor 5

J is on floor 6

> **Q9: If J is on floor 3, which of the following pairs of companies cannot be on consecutive floors?**

M and J

F and K

G and J

K and M

> **Q10: If F is on floor 5, which of the following cannot be true?**

G is on floor 4

K is on floor 4

M is on floor 2

M is on floor 3

Comment: Can you please edit by changing company 'I' to a different alphabet for better readability:-)

Comment: What about Q 1-6? Where did you get this questions from? here at Puzzling we like to attribute our sources.

Comment: this 'puzzle' is ridiculously easy.

Comment: Did this come from an LSAT?

Answer (score 4):

For No. 7:

> Instructions say that F must be lower than G. and K must be at 4. So, only option 2 satisfies the required condition.

For no. 8:

> Again K must be at 4. So, Option 3 is always wrong (Hence, the correct answer).

For no. 9:

> Option 1 is again wrong (and thus the correct option) because it violates the condition that J and M can't be in consecutive floors.

For no. 10:

> Option 1 can't be true (and again, the correct option) because G has to be higher than F. And if, F is at 5, G *has to* be at 6. Alternative method is that K is always at 4. Hence, G can never be at 4. That also leads to the same answer.